# Should I create separate endpoints for bulk CRUD operations REST?

Tags: rest, api, api-design

If I want to support both single and bulk create, update, delete operations in my REST API, I have two options:

Create single endpoint for both single and bulk operations, e.g:

```
POST docs/
{content...}

POST docs/
[
    {content...},
    {content..,}
]
```

Or to create separate endpoints for both single and bulk operations, e.g:

```
POST docs/
{content...}

POST docs/bulk
[
    {content...},
    {content...}
]
```

Which option is better in term of: REST guidelines and design principles, and why? many thanks.

Comment: It looks like the difference is using a JSON array vs. a single JSON object - can you detect the use of an array vs. object using a single endpoint?

Comment: sure I can, but should I? if my API will be consumed by many, which option is more conventionally done (more intuitive)? and do both obey to REST principles? @Dai

Comment: What do the actions represent, exactly? If you're just exposing raw data over HTTP then have you considered using OData instead of defining your own REST API? As OData automatically handles CRUD and there are many OData libraries available for many platforms.

Comment: Mainly: creation, update, delete and querying 'Doc' resource with many validations. I do not know about OData, I will check it thank you.

Comment: OData sounds exactly like what you need :)

Comment: REST has no specific guidelines on this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by [Josh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12447201/josh), REST doesn't offer guidance on resource design.  Any information that can be named can be a resource, and all resources should understand messages the same way.

HTTP does no better; it defines message semantics without encouraging any particular resource design.

When you are modifying a *single* resource, then HTTP encourages you to POST to that resource in an indirect way -- the rules for [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) indicate which resource should have its locally cached representations invalidated.

But we haven't standardized a general mechanism for invalidating *arbitrary* resources.  This means that you don't have a way to communicate your caching semantics to a general purpose HTTP component.